# Why doesn't this reactjs component code function as expected?

Tags: reactjs

Expected:

1. On changing the text in the input box, the title updates to the
   message  converted to uppercase.
2. On pressing the Send button the updated message is printed in the
   console

Results:

1. Doesn't work. Error in console saying 'this' is undefined in the function textBoxChange. (It's defined in the render function but not in the textBoxChange function?)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/r11na/pen/qNKpQX

```
class App extends React.Component {
  textBoxChange(e) {
    this.props.text = e.target.value;
  };

  sendMessage(e) {
    console.log("Send message:" + this.props.text);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Your Message: {this.props.text.toUpperCase()}</h3>
        <MessageBox textBoxChange={this.textBoxChange} sendMessage={this.sendMessage} text={this.props.text}/>
      </div>
    );
  };
};

const MessageBox = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="row column">
      <textarea onChange={props.textBoxChange} value={props.text}></textarea>
      <button onClick={props.sendMessage} className="button">Send</button>
      <br/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: First off all you need use `states` instead of `props` - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKYEVG., because you can not assign new values to `props`.

Comment: Thanks Alexander makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced `props` with `state`, added `bind(this)` methods and little changes:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { text: this.props.text };
  }

  textBoxChange(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  };

  sendMessage(e) {
    console.log("Send message:" + this.state.text);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Your Message: {this.state.text.toUpperCase()}</h3>
        <MessageBox
          textBoxChange={this.textBoxChange.bind(this)}
          sendMessage={this.sendMessage.bind(this)}
          text={this.state.text}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

const MessageBox = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="row column">
      <textarea onChange={props.textBoxChange.bind(this)} value={props.text}></textarea>
      <button onClick={props.sendMessage.bind(this)} className="button">Send</button>
      <br/>
    </div>
  );
};
```